# Integrity Error with null=True on field

Tags: django, postgresql

Edit: **solved** - the issue was not with my main model, but with another model that is created on changed to `Lead`. Django works!

This is stumping me. **I create a model where the field is nullable `null=True`, but my database throws an IntegrityError.** It works on my development machine...

Here's the abbreviated traceback:

`IntegrityError: null value in column "score_updated_on" violates not-null constraint`

Here is the model:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ...
    score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=3, max_digits=7, blank=True, null=True)
    score_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I have run all migrations. I went into psql and ran `ALTER TABLE leads_lead ALTER COLUMN score_updated_on DROP NOT NULL;`. No change.

Nuke it all and reinitialize the DB? That's days of work, but this process can't continue unless I can accept null values.

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Yes - I have made and run all migrations. Is there a way to reset and rerun all migrations?

Comment: Solved. See edit up top...